# What advantages does Sass provide over regular CSS?

Tags: css, syntax, language-features, sass

I'm trying to decide on technologies for a presentation layer. I have heard Sass talked about enthusiastically but am resistant to learn something new without knowing why it's better than the alternative - in this case plain CSS. Any feedback on Sass would be welcome.

Edit: This is also a good discussion on this:

[SASS: The Better, More Powerful CSS](http://www.intridea.com/2009/2/4/sass-the-better-more-powerful-css?blog=company)

Comment: I've never heard of Sass, and I can't find anything on-line about it.  Chances are it's something proprietary, and will lock you in in a way that CSS was designed to prevent.

Comment: Sass generates CSS, and consequently there's no lock-in. If you wanted to abandon SASS and use pure CSS mid project, it would just be a matter of editing the generated CSS files as you traditionally would.

Comment: On top of that, SASS can convert .css to .sass files and vice versa, using a simple command-line tool, so exporting your files as normal css is easy enough.

Comment: Sass is also open-source (MIT licensed), so definitely not proprietary. The website is here: http://sass-lang.com/.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a [screencast](http://vimeo.com/4335944) that shows Sass and Compass (the Sass-based stylesheet framework) in action. It's an hour long, but it shows how Sass and Compass work and how they enable new ways of approaching website design by enabling sharing of implementation without compromising the content/presentation boundary.

Comment: Compass is fantastic - highly recommended.